# C++ Best way to replace code with function

Tags: c++, function, c++11, for-loop

If I have a function like this:

```
void Func(T a)
{
    T b, c, d;
    for (uint i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        b = Call1(a);
        c = Call2(b);
        d = Call3(c);
    }
}
```

and I basically just want to make the function look something like form:

```
void Func(T a)
{
    T d;
    for (uint i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        d = Call(a);
}
```

where `Call` is something like this:

```
T Call(T a)
{
    T b, c;
    b = Call1(a);
    c = Call2(b);
    d = Call3(c);
    return d;
}
```

Is `Call` going to have to reinitialise `b` and `c` everytime it is called in the loop?  Should I, perhaps, use `static T b, c` instead in the `Call function`?

Comment: What about using an inline function? Call(b,c,d);

Comment: I would've thought the compiler would inline it if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked:

> Is Call going to have to reinitialise b and c everytime it is called in the loop?

The answer to that is, Yes.

You asked:

> Should I, perhaps, use static T b, c instead in the Call function?

The answer to that is, Most likely not.

If you are concerned about the cost of creating an instance of `T`, you can optimize the function a little bit by using:

```
T Call(T a)
{
    return Call3(Call2(Call1(a)));
}
```

Comment: Okay, what would be the issue with using `static`?  Will `static` be slower as it won't store the data in cache?  Also, is there a better way than `return Call3(Call2(Call1(a)));` as this will start becoming quiet cumbersome once the code in the for-loop becomes more complex, for example, if I want `if-else` statements.

Comment: A `static` variable in a function makes sense only if you need to maintain state from one call to the next. I don't think a `static` variable would change anything as far as performance is concerned.

Comment: @Jean-Luc `static` could be better performance-wise but it does make your `Call` more fragile. For example it makes it *not* thread safe.

Comment: @RSahu if there is a constructor then `static` could be an optimisation ; a more common example of this is `long string_to_long(string s) { istringstream i(s); long m(0);  i >> m; return m; }`  . It turns out to be a huge speed improvement to make `i` static (even though you also have to `.clear()` each time)

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I have been bitten by performance problems associated with `stringstream` in the past. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

I will show you a more generalized solution to your problem. *Herb Sutter* has in the book `More Exceptional C++` a nice chapter about how to simulate **nested functions**:

```
template <class T> class F {
private:
  //T retval; // if you need Func to return
  //here you can have members that simulate local variables in the original Func
  // T x, y, z;

  // the nested function(s)
  void Call(a) {
    T b, c;
    b = Call1(a);
    c = Call2(b);
    d = Call3(c);
    // ... = x;
    return d;
  }

public:
  int F(T a) { // original function Func, now a consturctor
    T d;
    //x = ...
    for (uint i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        d = Call(a);
    // if you need the original function to return:
    // retval = ...;
  }
  // if the original function needs to return:
  T operator()() const {
    return retval;
  }

};
```